# Issue with Apache Solr indexing large file on Mac OS X - Mavericks

Tags: java, macos, solr, out-of-memory, large-files

I'm getting the following error trying to index a large file (20GB) containing around 70MM 
records. This error occurs processing over 25MM records.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)

at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)

at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)

at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:535)

at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:322)

The same process is able to index 100MM records (30GB) on a windows 32-bit machine. Any clue?

Thanks.

Comment: Presumably the default memory allocation on your Mac is smaller than that on your windows machine. Use the `Xmx` flag to allocate more RAM.

Comment: Which JVM implementations do you use? JRockit or Oracle or something else? How much heap (Xmx) do you give the VM?